# Sencha Touch Charts iteminfo

Tags: sencha-touch-2

in the sencha touch documentary http://docs-origin.sencha.com/touch/2.4/2.4.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.chart.interactions.ItemInfo, it is described how to handle iteminfo

```
interactions: [{
    type: 'iteminfo',
    listeners: {
        show: function(me, item, panel) {
            panel.setHtml('Stock Price: $' + item.record.get('price'));
        }
    }
}]
```

But when I apply this to my chart I get a

```
 Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
```

If I output the item with console.log, I don't get an object...

```
   <canvas class="x-surface" id="ext-element-614" height="214" width="1062" style="left: 0px; height: 214px; width: 1062px;"></canvas>
```

any idea how to get around with this in Sencha Touch 2.4.1

Comment: Have you added `store`? Console the store and tell me.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your store is null , that why you are gettinh this error,
 Have you added store ,

```
            new Ext.chart.AbstractChart({
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
width: 800,
height: 600,
**store: store1,**
axes: [ ...some axes options... ],
series: [ ...some series options... ],
interactions: [{
    type: 'iteminfo',
    listeners: {
        show: function(me, item, panel) {
            panel.setHtml('Stock Price: $' + item.record.get('price'));
        }
    }
 }]
 });
```